# Access data from other query?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I've done every auth-related GraphQL tutorial I can find, but I still can't really get my head around it.

If in my `Auth` component, I query for a token and user credentials like so:

```
const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LoginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
      user {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`
```

How do I access this data in another component? Every guide seems to say I wrap every component that needs user data in another `<Query>` element, so would every component need to attempt to log in?

With Redux I can add it to the store and just use `mapStateToProps` to get it without querying the server every time I need the user's name. Is that do-able in Apollo, or do I just write hundreds of queries for the same thing?

Comment: Hey mitch has my answer cleared things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would every component need to attempt to log in?

No every component wouldn't have to relog in, if you take a look at the apollo docs we can see it states:

- When the Query component mounts, Apollo Client creates an observable for our query. Our component subscribes to the result of the query via the Apollo Client cache.
- First, we try to load the query result from the Apollo cache. If it’s not in there, we send the request to the server.
- Once the data comes back, we normalize it and store it in the Apollo cache. Since the Query component subscribes to the result, it updates with the data reactively.

so if you fetch the user creds and store them in the cache the next time you go to fetch that item it will come from the cache if it's not in the cache it will refetch.

> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html